# what is the lldb cmd option '-w' used for in cmd line "type synthetic add -w"

Tags: lldb

once in lldb I run: `help type synthetic add`

there is a -w option:

```
-w <name> ( --category <name> )
            Add this to the given category instead of the default one.
```

what does the category here really mean?

I've seen some people use the lib name as the value, for example:

https://github.com/llvm-mirror/lldb/blob/master/examples/synthetic/unordered_multi.py

```
-w libcxx
```

is there any other usage? or any docs explain this?

Answer (score 0):

Type categories are an organizing convenience.  You can use the `type category` command to enable, disable, list or delete the summaries/synthetic children in that category.  Also the regular `type  list" command will group summaries by category. They don't have any other effect.